# code igniter re-writing get parameters with html encoded characters

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i'm new to codeigniter and trying to simply pass a GET variable to a controller function and have that controller search a database based on that GET variable string.  I am using ajax to fetch the returned view with results and display it back on the page..

my issue is that i have a link where onclick it will execute this javascript such as....

```
function fetchview(query_id2){
     $.ajax({

     url:'getProjectDetails/'+query_id2,
     dataType: "html",
     success: function(str){

                   $("#content").html(str);
              }
     });
}
```

the link itself is...

```
onclick="('query_id')";
```

the issue is that codeigniter AUTOMATICALLY passes the query_id2 to the 'getProjectDetails' function by replacing any + or even %20 with the "dash" character "-".

This is an issue because i need to query the database without any dashes....

any possible way to resolve this?

I have already tried url encoding the 'query_id' within the link... then url decoding within 'getProjectDetails' --this does not work as codeigniter still replaces %20 characters with dashes within 'getProjectDetails'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are trying to pass a string or some variable over to CI controller, get database results, and return data.

If you are trying to send query over jquery to php, use [jQuery post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function, send data via POST. Also, bind it with [jQuery click event](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Example:

```
$("#element").click(function() {
var url = "<?=site_url("getProjectDetails")?>";
var query_id = $("#query_id").val();
$.post(url, { 'query_id' : query_id }, function(data) {
       $("#content").html(data);
   }
});
```

the data is the html output from the php.

in CI controller, retrieve query_id using the following:

```
$this->input->post('query_id');
```